# Utilizar Sublime Text com Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, sublime-text-2

Estou em um novo projeto que utiliza o **Java WEB + Spring** no backend e eu faço apenas o front-end. Preciso manter o Eclipse aberto para rodar o servidor.

Entretanto, eu utilizo o **Sublime Text 2** na edição do html pois acho ele muito ágil com as extensões emmet, por exemplo.

O meu problema é que quando eu faço uma alteração no html através do **Sublime**, tenho que mudar a **janela do Windows** para o Eclipse para que ele atualize a o código editado e só então poder verificar no navegador a alteração.

Comment: O problema é que o sublime não faz o deploy dos arquivos modificados?

Comment: isso, quando troco a janela para o eclipse, com o arquivo que editei aberto, ele se atualiza sozinho e assim o eclipse faz o deploy.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119005/integrate-sublime-text-with-tomcat] aqui tem uma solução parecida... mas depois de alterar o arquivo demora até 1 minuto para receber a atualização do arquivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, até onde sei não é possível atualizar automaticamente as JSP's do projeto automaticamente pelo eclipse(caso você esteja em outro software, como o seu caso).

O que poderias verificar é o JRebel, é uma plataforma de hotdeploy para o eclipse, talvez possa ter algo como um "schedule de refresh".

O software pode ser baixado por aqui:
https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse/
E a licensa (não comercial) pode ser feita aqui:
https://my.jrebel.com/

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas acabei abandonando o Eclipse e instalando o apache a parte.