# Trabalhando com tomcat + Eclipse + SublimeText (Frontend)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, sublime-text-3

Estamos criando um projeto web utilizando o Eclipse (IDE) e SpringMVC. A equipe de desenvolvimento possui duas pessoas, separadas em Front-end e Back-end (estamos utilizando GIT para versionamento). Para o Front-end gostaríamos de utilizar o SublimeText ao invés do Eclipse. Porém o Sublime não faz deploy da aplicação no tomcat, o Eclipse faz isso automaticamente e também republica os arquivos alterados.

Qual é a melhor maneira de utilizar o SublimeText como editor Front-end (view) e Eclipse Back-end e ambos realizarem deploy da aplicação no tomcat ?

Comment: Acho que é o mesmo problema: [Utilizar Sublime Text com Eclipse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243374/91)

Answer (score 0):

Eu começaria rodando a aplicação **sem o eclipse**.

Vocês provavelmente utilizam Maven ou Gradle no projeto. Ambas ferramentas oferecem plugins ([maven](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html) | [gradle](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin)) para fazer deploy de um war com um simples comando no terminal. Após instalar a configurar o plugin, só rodar:

`mvn tomcat7:deploy`

ou

`gradle war tomcatRun`

Depois você poderia ainda instalar o [Glue](http://blog.codecarrot.net/glue-a-terminal-for-sublime-text/) e executar estes comandos dentro do Sublime.

Comment: criei um script, conforme comentou para realizar o deploy através do sublimeText e ele esta fazendo! Todavia, para cada alteração gerada em um arquivo front-end (jsp, css ou js), é necessário fazer um novo deploy (mvn tomcat7:deploy) para visualizar o resultado, isso leva um certo tempo. O eclipse possui um opção de atualizar o deploy automaticamente (Automatically publish when resources change). Saberia me dizer como posso fazer a mesma coisa sem o eclipse ? Ou ainda, fazer um hot deploy utilizando o maven ?

Comment: Você poderia criar um macro pra fazer o deploy sempre que salvar o arquivo ou ver [alternativas para hot deploy com o plugin do maven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846950).